# How to show the image in push notification (Gcm) php

Tags: php, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How do i send a push notification like in the following picture using PHP and GCM service.

i am currently sending the following data to GCM for normal push notifications

```
$message = array(
    'title' => 'Example Title',
    'subtitle' => 'Example Subtitle',
    'message' =>'Example Message',
    'tickerText' => 'XYZ',
    'vibrate' => '1',
    'sound' => '1',
);
```

to this url

https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

[image: Flipkart Image Push Notification]

Comment: post your android code also

Comment: i just generate a registration id from the android app. I want to send the push notification possibly without any change to android app's code

Comment: which format you send the message from server to mobile app

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to send a Notification Message, note the icon field [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support).

Another option would be to send the url to the image in the downstream message then retrieve the image within the mobile app, then use the image to construct the notification.

Comment: I want the images to be sent from the server. when using your second method wouldnt that result in two notifications being shown. If it doesnt is there some sample which i could refer to, to do this

Comment: The second option will not result in a second Notification. When the notification comes in you would make the request for the image. When the image is received you can then show the notification. Here is a sample that shows a notification when a GCM message is received https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java